# Intuition for MCMC and stationary distribution?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stationarity, monte-carlo

Studying up on Markov-chain Monte Carlo sampling and the theory behind the stationary distribution, I want to validate it.

Say we have a stochastic transition matrix $p$ describing events in space $\Omega$. We also have a stationary distribution $\pi$ which is the target distribution from which we want to draw samples.

The existence of $\pi$ makes MCMC estimation possible because generating new values of $p$ from $\Omega$ will always result in new values with which we can estimate parameters of $\pi$ per the stationary equation $\pi p = \pi$.

Am I understanding the *why* of MCMC sampling correctly? I know plain English is less precise than mathematical definitions/ proofs, but I'm hoping to strengthen my understanding of the conceptual framework.

Comment: "We also have a stationary distribution $\pi$" is unclear: it should be "the transition matrix enjoys the stationary distribution $\pi$"

Comment: @Xi'an Can you elaborate on this: "the transition matrix enjoys the stationary distribution $\pi$"? What do you mean by the word *enjoys* specifically? Is it correct that $\pi$ describes the probability distribution over events in space $\Omega$ whereas $p$ describes the probability of *transitioning* from one state to another?

Comment: @samvoit4 Not every transition matrix (or MC chain characterized by the transition matrix) has a stationary distribution; thus $\pi$ might not exist. This is meant by "enjoys," I believe. Also, the transition matrix "does not describe the events in space $\Omega$" it describes how the MC chain will move in subsequent iterations. Now, if $\pi$ exists, this means that as the number of transitions grows to infinity, the chain will eventually reach a state in which every next iteration will visit $\omega \in \Omega$ with the probability described by $\pi$. Hence the equation $\pi p = \pi$.